# Jquery Slice, substr, substring not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to split the content in two different tags. The first variable (summarySentence1and2) fails to store result, and the second variable (summarySentanceOthers) stores all content of the source field. Instead I want to split the content from 0, 28 in first variable and 28 to last in another variable.

```js
var summaryText = $(this).find('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text();
var summarySentence1and2 = summaryText.split(' ').slice(0, 28).join(' ');
var summarySentanceOthers = summaryText.split(' ').slice(28).join(' ');

//alert(summarySentence1and2);
//alert(summarySentanceOthers);

$('#first').text(summarySentence1and2);
$('#second').text(summarySentanceOthers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
 <div class="field-name-field-review-summary">
We had an excellent guide in Antonino who took us on some excellent routes and had extensive knowledge of the area, fauna and history of the volcanoes and the evolution of the landscape. The hotels and included meals were disappointing and should have been of a higher quality.
</div>
</div>

<p id="first"></p>
<p id="second"></p>
```

Comment: The only issue I can see with your code is it's not wrapped in the document ready function, when it is it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding .trim() solves the issue

```js
var summaryText = $(this).find('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following I've modified you code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var summaryText = $(this).find('.review-body .field-name-field-  review-summary').text();
        var summarySentence1and2 = summaryText.split(' ').slice(0, 28).join(' ');
        var summarySentanceOthers = summaryText.split(' ').slice(28).join(' ');

        //alert(summarySentence1and2);
        //alert(summarySentanceOthers);

        $('#first').text(summarySentence1and2);
        $('#second').text(summarySentanceOthers);
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is due to the fact your code is not wrapped in the [jQuery document ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```js
$(function() {
  var summaryText = $(this).find('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text();
  var summarySentence1and2 = summaryText.split(' ').slice(0, 28).join(' ');
  var summarySentanceOthers = summaryText.split(' ').slice(28).join(' ');

  $('#first').text(summarySentence1and2);
  $('#second').text(summarySentanceOthers);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
  <div class="field-name-field-review-summary">
    We had an excellent guide in Antonino who took us on some excellent routes and had extensive knowledge of the area, fauna and history of the volcanoes and the evolution of the landscape. The hotels and included meals were disappointing and should have
    been of a higher quality.
  </div>
</div>

<p id="first"></p>
<p id="second"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do either:

```
var summaryText = $('body').find('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text();
```

or simply,

```
var summaryText = $('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text();
```

Your `this` reference refers to the `window` object which does not know about the body of your content.

```js
var summaryText = $('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text();
var summarySentence1and2 = summaryText.split(' ').slice(0, 28).join(' ');
var summarySentanceOthers = summaryText.split(' ').slice(28).join(' ');

console.log(summarySentence1and2);
console.log(summarySentanceOthers);

$('#first').text(summarySentence1and2);
$('#second').text(summarySentanceOthers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
  <div class="field-name-field-review-summary">
    We had an excellent guide in Antonino who took us on some excellent routes and had extensive knowledge of the area, fauna and history of the volcanoes and the evolution of the landscape. The hotels and included meals were disappointing and should have
    been of a higher quality.
  </div>
</div>

<p id="first"></p>
<p id="second"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for my understanding for your question i did.
Please use "$('.review-body').text();" instead of "$(this).find('.review-body .field-name-field-review-summary').text();"

```js
var summaryText = $('.review-body').text();
var summarySentence1and2 = summaryText.split(' ').slice(0, 28).join(' ');
var summarySentanceOthers = summaryText.split(' ').slice(28).join(' ');

//alert(summarySentence1and2);
//alert(summarySentanceOthers);

$('#first').text(summarySentence1and2);
$('#second').text(summarySentanceOthers);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-body" itemprop="reviewBody">
 <div class="field-name-field-review-summary">
We had an excellent guide in Antonino who took us on some excellent routes and had extensive knowledge of the area, fauna and history of the volcanoes and the evolution of the landscape. The hotels and included meals were disappointing and should have been of a higher quality.
</div>
</div>

<p id="first"></p>
<p id="second"></p>
```